# Parsing YAML - instantiating elements in a list using the correct subtypes, without using YAML tags?

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing, yaml

When parsing a list with items of different subtypes using snakeYAML, how do you instantiate objects of the correct subtypes without using YAML tags?

I’d like to avoid using YAML tags if possible to remain compatible with JSON parsers, but I can't figure out how to parse something like the following, and instantiate the correct subtypes of Control:

```
controls:
- type: button
  width: 10
  height: 12
  hasLED: Yes

- type: knob
  resistence: 0.6
  rotates360Degrees: Yes

- type: slider
  width: 1
  height: 300
  motorized: Yes
```

Can that done using snakeYAML?

---

Or with a YAML file in this format?:

```
controls:
- button:
  width: 10
  height: 12
  hasLED: Yes

- knob:
  resistence: 0.6
  rotates360Degrees: Yes

- slider:
  width: 3
  height: 50
  motorized: Yes
```

Finally, a related question: which of the two previous chunks of YAML would be considered the more elegant or "preferred" way of representing that information (without using tags)? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to rewrite the YAML nodes so that `type: button` becomes `!button` before the constructor sees it (this will work for your first YAML layout). You can do this with a custom composer:

```java
public class MyComposer extends Composer {
    public MyComposer(Parser parser, Resolver resolver) {
        super(parser, resolver, new LoaderOptions());
    }

    public MyComposer(Parser parser, Resolver resolver, LoaderOptions loadingConfig) {
        super(parser, resolver, loadingConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected Node composeMappingNode(String anchor, List<CommentLine> blockComments) {
        MappingNode node = (MappingNode)super.composeMappingNode(anchor, blockComments);
        // assume the node having Tag.MAP means that it had no explicit tag.
        // this is wrong for nodes tagged with `!!map` but nobody does that.
        if (Tag.MAP.equals(node.getTag()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < node.getValues().size(); i++) {
                NodeTuple t = node.getValues().get(i);
                if (t.getKeyNode() instanceof ScalarNode &&
                        "type".equals(((ScalarNode)t.getKeyNode()).getValue())) {
                    node.setTag(new Tag(
                            "!" + ((ScalarNode)t.getValueNode()).getValue()));
                    node.getValues().remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

Sadly, the `Yaml` class doesn't let us override `loadFromReader` which needs to be modified to use our custom composer ([the method is private](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/dd0635ae3f79fe85520da667b523ee79c0823597/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml.java#lines-487)). I advise to simply copy the parts of the Yaml class you actually need and change `loadFromReader` to

```java
    private Object loadFromReader(StreamReader sreader, Class<?> type) {
        Composer composer = new MyComposer(new ParserImpl(sreader,
                loadingConfig.isProcessComments()), resolver, loadingConfig);
        constructor.setComposer(composer);
        return constructor.getSingleData(type);
    }
```

You can then register custom constructors for the tags `!button`, `!knob` and `!slider` as if they existed in the input instead of `type: button` etc.

---

The more conventional way to do it would be to supply a root tag and a custom constructor for that root tag. The custom constructor will then need to arrange calling custom constructors for the items of the sequence. This approach is better if you do not want to convert `type: droggeljug` to `!droggeljug` everywhere. However it is likely more code and more complicated to do.

---

> which of the two previous chunks of YAML would be considered the more elegant

What you do in the second YAML is that you basically add keys with empty values to your mappings. This approach seems strange and has the problem that your types must not carry the same name as their properties (while with the first approach, they simply may not have a property `type`).

You could go with this instead:

```yaml
controls:
- button:
    width: 10
    height: 12
    hasLED: Yes
# etc
```

This is the fix to the problem that a property named `type` would otherwise be disallowed. The custom composer approach does not work with this structure, though. Whether this structure makes more sense from an implementation-agnostic view is hard to say. I think both methods are not ideal when a YAML author expects

```yaml
- !button
  width: 10
  height: 12
  hasLED: Yes
```

to be the way of supplying the target type of a YAML node. Tags explicitly exist in YAML because the type indicator should ideally not be part of the value structure.

Comment: flyx, you make a lot of great points! Do you think it would be reasonable/useful/elegant/possible to have the parser use YAML tags if present in the file, and if not present, to look for a specially named field (one with a single consistent name, which starts with a special character, like “@type”) to get type information from using the method you describe?

The goal would be to have the ability to emit/parse a version of the file which is valid JSON (since I'm not using anchor/aliases, or other YAML-specific features) for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @user10264746 I would, for maintainability reasons, have a separate step that transforms the JSON-like input into YAML and pipes that to the loading step. This has multiple benefits: You can trivially phase out compatibility by deleting that step, you can offer users the ability to transform their current JSON files into YAML but capturing the transformed output, and you can decide beforehand whether to use that step or not (e.g. only for `.json` files or whatever your setup allows).